# Как повторить заданную мной функцию несколько раз?

Tags: python

```
import random 
def repit_num():
    num1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    num2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    a=random.choice(num1)
    b=random.choice(num2)
    print(a,'',b)


for repit_num() in range(11):
    repit_num()
```

Comment: repeat.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

два одинаковых способа (просто в 2 и 1 строку)

```
import random

def repit_num():
    num1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    num2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    a=random.choice(num1)
    b=random.choice(num2)
    print(a,'',b)


# способ 1
for i in range(11):
    repit_num()

# способ 2
[repit_num() for i in range(11)]
```

А если определить функцию как `def repit_num(x)`, то можно и 3 способ использовать

```
import random

def repit_num(tmp):
    num1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    num2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    a=random.choice(num1)
    b=random.choice(num2)
    print(a,'',b)

[*map(repit_num, range(11))]
```

но это изврат уже

Comment: Если извращаться, то так: `def repit_num(*_):`

Comment: @vp_arth, тогда и в `for` `_` ставить :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(11):
    repit_num()
```

Comment: выдает ошибку: File "random.ur.py", line 10
    for repit_num() in range(11):
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Comment: Ну так Нужно for repit_num() in range(11):
    repit_num() заменить на  for i in range(11):
    repit_num(). Хоть чуть чуть то разобраться что вы вообще спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью декораторов :)

```
from functools import update_wrapper
import random


def repeat_function(n):
    def repeat_function_inner(f):
        update_wrapper(repeat_function_inner, f)

        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(n):
                f(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner
    return repeat_function_inner

@repeat_function(15)
def repit_num():
    num1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    num2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    a=random.choice(num1)
    b=random.choice(num2)
    print(a,'',b)


repit_num()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for __ in range(11):
    repit_num()
```

Тем вызов функции повторяется 11 раз — для чисел `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10` из `range(11)`.

*Так как эти числа самые не используются,* принято не употреблять в цикле `for` обычное имя переменной, как например `i` или `element`, а *специальное* — один или 2 знака подчёркивания (`_`).

Comment: вы сказали что нужно писать `_` а сами в коде пишите `__`)

Comment: @Danis, нет, я сказал «один **или 2** знака подчёркивания».

Comment: извините незаметил, зря быканул

Comment: @Danis, всё в порядке, и у меня это случается. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 
def repit_num():
    num1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    num2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    a=random.choice(num1)
    b=random.choice(num2)
    print(a,'',b)


exec("repit_num()\n" * 11)
```

Comment: всё коротко и ясно,спасибо